# SQL Group By, Distinct confusion

Tags: sql, .net

I have a program that is linked to a sql DB, with 2 tables - `Customers` and `SInfo`.

Customers has the normal columns:

```
CUSTOMERID   (Primary Key)
FIRSTNAME
LASTNAME
EMAIL
```

SInfo has details about the Customer:

```
SSheetID     (Primary Key)
CustomerID
SerialNumber
```

When I use the query builder in .net, I use an `inner join` to combine the tables, and use a filter to search for a serial number, but I am getting an error when the primary key is shown more than once.

[image]

I tried to use `distinct`, but if one field was different, I would get the error, and `GROUP BY` is killing me.

So my question is, what would be the best practice if a Customer (CustomerID) has the same Serial Number more than once, but I just want to show that CustomerID once, but still fill out FirstName, LastName, Email?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please don't use pictures. Just put in the text.

Comment: Show us your `TRY` ?

Comment: Why would you store the same `SerialNumber` and `CustomerID` in the `SInfo` table? Perhaps you should remove the `SSheetID` column and make the PK   `CustomerID,SerialNumber` to ensure there can't be repeats. Or put an index/constraint across both columns to enforce a unique value.

Comment: You say you want one row per customer, even if he has rows in sinfo table? How do you chose SSheetID, CustomerID and SerialNumber in that case? Add more sample table data (as text), and expected result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various options...

via `distinct`:

```
select distinct c.* -- or better: more specific c. columns
from SInfo s
inner join Customers c on c.CUSTOMERID = s.CustomerID
where s.SerialNumber = @serial
```

via `exists`:

```
select *
from Customers c
where exists (
    select 1 from SInfo s
    where s.CustomerID = c.CUSTOMERID
    and s.SerialNumber = @serial)
```

but as noted in the comments: a unique constraint over `SInfo.SerialNumber`, or perhaps spanning `SInfo.SerialNumber and SInfo.CustomerID` - probably makes sense.

Comment: I noticed I never gave you credit for your answer.  Thanks a lot, it worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Like what Turophile said i think the data in SInfo table got some problem.so what you should do is to clean the table SInfo first or you can try this:

```
    select a.CustomerID,a.SerialNumber,b.FirstName from
    (select distinct (CustomerID),SerialNumber from SInfo)a 
    inner join Customers b on a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use natural join for this case because when you use natural join, it will match people with the same Customer ID and then use GROUP BY so it will show the name one time.

```
select first_name, last_name, email
from customer natural join Sinfo
group by customerID, first_name, last_name, email
```